# Ways to display information in a multiple option menu

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a display menu with different information depending on the "button" you click.

If it is only a button, my code is working fine. The problem comes when I include multiple options.

This is a representation of what I want to build: https://ibb.co/KyPY53c

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to build `tabs`. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) is what you are asking for. Please provide more explanation or code with your next questions.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was doing the wrong search, searching for buttons. Really appreciate your help!